# how could I set auto-expand in Paw HTTP client for mac?

Tags: paw-app

I've installed Paw HTTP client in my mac.

and I used a little for testing API.

but I discovered that all responses were collapsed.

I want to set auto expand for all responses.

how could I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold `alt` while clicking the expansion arrow to fully expand the JSON response, when resending the request the response will follow the previous expansion level.